# How do I disable the system beep in FreeBSD 10.1?

Tags: freebsd, audio

How do I disable the system beep on the console in FreeBSD 10.1?

The recommended commands don't work.

The `sysctl` setting:

```
# sysctl hw.syscons.bell=0
hw.syscons.bell: 1 -> 0
# sysctl -a | grep bell
hw.syscons.bell: 0
```

Backspace still results in an ear splitting beep.

Found [another suggestion](http://www.quitsendingmetrash.com/lrn/unix/freeBsd/systemBeepOff.php), to use `kbdcontrol`:

```
# kbdcontrol -b off
#
```

Nope, still beeps.

**My system details:**

An old Gateway MD-78 series laptop (with Intel GM45 Express Chipset), without a hardware volume knob, and decidedly loud PC speaker volume.

I'm running FreeBSD 10.1.

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD raktop 10.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE #0 r274401: Tue Nov 11 21:02:49 UTC 2014     root@releng1.nyi.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

**Update:**

I'm running [`vt` a.k.a. `newcons`](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Newcons), and eventually found that I could turn the beep off with:

```
kbdcontrol -b quiet.off
```

which can be put into `/etc/rc.conf`, to make the change permanent, as:

```
allscreens_kbdflags="-b quiet.off"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're running `vt` a.k.a. `newcons`, try:

```
kbdcontrol -b quiet.off
```

If that works, you can make it permanent in your `/etc/rc.conf`:

```
allscreens_kbdflags="-b quiet.off"
```

Background:

After running `kbdcontrol` from an Xterm and seeing it print out an escape sequence, I realized that it is just trying to send a command to the terminal emulation in the console driver, and it might need to be sending something different depending on the console driver; then I looked for and found the answer specific to `newcons`: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2014-April/049463.html

Comment: I'm not sure what's up with the `keybell="NO"` vs. `keybell="off"` as suggested in `/etc/defaults/rc.conf`, but in any case neither of those disabled the beep for me.

Answer (score 6):

Use `sysctl -a | grep bell` to see which knobs you've got. vt is probably what is being used these days.

`sudo sysctl kern.vt.enable_bell=0` works in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Pulled from freebsd forum [post](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/disable-change-audio-bell.38631/):

> You can disable bell if you set MIB hw.syscons.bell value to 0. Just type

```
sysctl hw.syscons.bell=0
```

> To save changes permanently after reboot your machine

```
# echo "hw.syscons.bell=0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

:)

Comment: As I said, I tried that and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've just "disabled" the system beep in a chinese mini PC using a very simple and effective method like the one shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNZ-w5XYVZ8). Seriously :)

In fact, it was not a system beep, it was a BIOS beep and there was not any option to disable it there. But there is always some workaround. :) Now I enjoy absolute silence. :)

I just disassembled the buzzer and removed the vibrating membrana. This was the only way to force it get mute. There was no option in BIOS to turn off the self test sound, and it was very loud and annoying. After all, silence is more valuable than a 200-dollar PC.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jasonwryan. The answer is: I just disassembled the buzzer and removed the vibrating membrana. This was the only way to force it get mute. There was no option in BIOS to turn off the self test sound, and it was very loud and annoying. After all, silence is more valuable than a 200-dollar PC. :)

Comment: I edited it into your answer, it is important (people reviewing your post votes mainly for the main content, not for the comments below it). Here is your first upvote, too. :-)

Comment: I suppose that's a good possibility to consider, as some people are just never going to use their built-in speakers much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing which worked in FreeBSD 10.3 was:

```
kern.vt.enable_bell=0
```

Comment: +1, this is the only think that worked on FreeBSD 11.0, contrary to the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be system dependent. I have FreeBSD installed on an external hard drive and can verify that on an Acer laptop it the sysctl `hw.syscons.bell=0` worked, while on a Lenovo system I had to use `kern.vt.enable_bell=0`.

This is despite using vt on both devices.